# flash website content box hiding the menu

Tags: flash, onmouseover, onmousemove

My website is: http://harringtonplanningdesign.com
When I move the cursor on the flash box the menu is disappearing. How can I keep the menu from hiding when the cursor is on the flash content box? That means I do not want to hide the menu when the mouse is moved.

The home page code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Harrington Planning + Design</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="com/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="com/swfaddress/swfaddress.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="com/pixelbreaker/swfmacmousewheel.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        #flashcontent {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="flashcontent">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        var so = new SWFObject('container.swf', 'container', '100%', '100%', '9', '#FFFFFF');
        so.useExpressInstall('com/swfobject/expressinstall.swf');
        so.addParam('allowFullScreen','true');  
        so.addParam('menu','false');
        if( so.write('flashcontent') )
            {
            var macmousewheel=new SWFMacMouseWheel(so);
        }
    // ]]>
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That behavior seems to be defined in Flash (not the HTML you posted above), since your entire site is Flash content, filling the entire browser window.

Comment: @ Lars Blåsjö, there is some flash content bottom of the code I posted. Isn't it covering the menu?

Comment: The menu is part of the Flash content. It is all Flash, all of the content ("100%" width and height).

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit code of your .swf, adding some MouseEvent's into it. If this variant is suitable for you, show me your AS-code, I'll help.